# Logic expressions for an English verse.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

**Question:**

This is an assignment question that I am having trouble with. The question goes like this.

[image]

**What I did:**

I made the predicate logic expression as follows.
$$\forall x\ LOVES(x, MYBABY)\ \wedge\ \forall x\ (x=ME \Longleftrightarrow LOVES(MYBABY, x))$$
Please tell me if this is correct. Also, I can't seem to find any logic on how to end up with $ME=MYBABY$, so please help with that as well. Sorry if this question seemed too naïve or seemed like I am getting an assignment done from you. Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation is technically correct, but the instructions don't list $\Longleftrightarrow$ as a permissible connective, so try to rewrite it with the connectives given.

Hint for the second question: The first part says that everybody loves $mybaby$. This implies in particular that $mybaby$ loves $mybaby$. Now think about how to use the rest to derive that $me = mybaby$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this... I have understood the rest :)